# User-defined conversions sequence

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Before I studied the `explicit` keyword, my teacher said: "compiler doesn't execute consecutive user defined conversion". If it is true, are there any errors in my code? Or have I misunderstood my teacher? I'm working in VS2017.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

class Myclass {
public:
    Myclass() {
        std::cout << "Myclass" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Myclass1 {
public:
    Myclass1(Myclass m) {
        std::cout << "Myclass1" << std::endl;
    }
};
class Myclass2{
public:
    Myclass2(Myclass1 m) {
        std::cout << "Myclass2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> compiler doesn't execute consecutive user defined conversion

Your teacher is right. In your code sample it means `Myclass` cannot be converted to `Myclass1` when you assign in:

```
Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};
```

Because constructor expects `Myclass1` when creating `Myclass2`, and compiler cannot consecutively convert `Myclass` to `Myclass1` and then use it for creating `Myclass2`. But if you have following line:

```
Myclass1 m2 = Myclass{};
```

It will work, because constructor of `Myclass1` takes `Myclass` as argument.

**Update:**

You may ask why this works:

```
Myclass2 m2 {Myclass{}};
```

Because in this case, constructor is called and conversion can be done implicitly unless you declare `Myclass1` as `explicit` which will fail code compilation (Thanks [Fureeish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7151494/fureeish) for reminder), but in:

```
Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};
```

is like calling copy-constructor which needs reference. so if you write it like this, it will work:

```
Myclass2 m2 = Myclass1(Myclass{});
```

As [EVG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1625187/evg) mentioned, `Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};` is accepted by VS 2017 if the conformance mode (/permissive-) is not activated.

Comment: Worth noting that OP mentioned `explicit`. In your first example in your edit, there is a temporary `Myclass1` object created *implicitely* from `Myclass` instance (that's why there is a `Myclass2` constructor invoked, which requires `Myclass1` object). If you make `Myclass1`'s constructor `explicit`, it will fail

Comment: @Fureeish I will add your comment.

Comment: `Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};` is accepted by VS 2017 if the conformance mode (`/permissive-`) is not activated.

Comment: @Evg I didn't know that. I will add it too.

Answer (score 8):

The line

```
 Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};
```

means *copy-initialization*. Citing [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

> If `T` is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of `other` is not `T` or derived from `T` [...], user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of `other` to `T` [...] are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution.

Citing [further](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> A user-defined conversion consists of zero or one non-explicit single-argument constructor or non-explicit conversion function call.

So, `Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};` is not acceptable because it would involve two user-defined conversions.

---

Now let's take a look at

```
Myclass2 m2 {Myclass{}};
```

suggested in **Afshin**'s answer. This is a *direct-initialization*. The rules are [different](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

> The constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

The constructor of `Myclass2` accepts `Myclass1`, and you need one user-defined conversion to get `Myclass1` from `Myclass`. Hence, it compiles.

---

Note that in VS *copy-initilization* is treated like *direct-initilization* if conformance mode (`/premissive-`) is not activated (by default). So, VS accepts `Myclass2 m2 = Myclass{};` treating it as *direct-initilization*. See [this document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are burying the lede: The code you’ve written is indeed *invalid*. MSVC accepts it by default, but MSVC is wrong to do so. You can force MSVC to be stricter by using the command line switch `/permissive-`. (*You should use that switch*.)

[Other compilers (GCC, clang), reject it.](https://godbolt.org/z/9nJTpb)

All compilers accept the code once you change the copy initialisation to direct initialisation as shown in the other answers.